# Is it possible to get the target back from a Process object?

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I have a `multiprocessing.Process` object. During construction we passed `target` and `args` in it. Is it possible to get those 2 values back? Or at least some kind of hint about what target the current Process object is using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, although we are not supposed to (as can be deduced from the API designer's decision to use attributes that starts with an underscore).

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def foo(x):
    print(x)

p = Process(target=foo, args=(1,))
print(p._target)
# <function foo at 0x000002457042B158>
print(p._args)
# (1,)
p._target(*p._args) 
# 1
```

Comment: @Wang I think a better approach to "clone" a process would be to use `deepcopy`: `from copy import deepcopy ; p2 = deepcopy(p1)`

Comment: not a exact clone, I need to change part of the _args